# How can I make a navbar with a centered logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a navbar with centered logo, but I can't do it the right way.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.circle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 550%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Menu</a>
  <a href="">Menu</a>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <a href="">Menu</a>
  <a href="">Menu</a>
```

I was expecting something like this, which I did in Photoshop:
[image: Logo]

Comment: You already *have* a navbar with a logo in the center. What **specifically** about your existing code does not match up with your desired outcome? Are you trying to increase the height of the navbar? Make the inner circle smaller? Space out the links? Etc...

Answer (score 0):

use `justify-content:space-between;` instead of `justify-content:center;` and add two divs.

```
<nav>
  <div>   <!--div 1-->
    <a href="">Menu</a>
    <a href="">Menu</a></div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <div> <!--div 2-->
    <a href="">Menu</a>
    <a href="">Menu</a></div>
</nav>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.circle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 550%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="">Menu</a>
    <a href="">Menu</a></div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <div>
    <a href="">Menu</a>
    <a href="">Menu</a></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

demo: https://codepen.io/phong18/pen/KKPyzro

html:

```
<nav>
  <div class="left-box">
    <a href="">Menu</a>
    <a href="">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <div class="right-box">
    <a href="">Menu</a>
    <a href="">Menu</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

add more css:

```
.left-box,.right-box{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-box{
  text-align: left;
}
.right-box{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try with this code view in full page  mode

```css
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .navbar-brand-centered {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        display: block;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
    .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
        margin-left: -80px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">Brand</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>          
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```